# Android - How to play more than one Video in VideoView when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm about to use 3 different videos with different buttons using only one `VideoView`. What I want is when I clicked `Button` 1, video 1 will play on screen, and `Button` 2 video 2 will play. this will only happen in 1 `VideoView`. 
Is it possible? because I also try to array images using one `ImageView`. I don't think on VideoView if will work. 
can someone help me. code is much better thank you.

Comment: Use both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662390/how-to-stop-video-playing-in-videoview-programmatically-in-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229140/playing-multiple-videos-using-videoview

Comment: @Androider thank you it really helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yes i think it's possible

Onclick of 3 different buttons you should set different resources for VideoView

eg.
VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
Button btn1,btn2,btn3,

btn1.setOnclick{
video.setVideoURI(uri[0]);
}

btn2.setOnclick{
video.setVideoURI(uri[1]);
}

btn3.setOnclick{
video.setVideoURI(uri[2]);
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, I'll try this one. thank you for the response